# Issue in removing a value from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I get a list of values from a source. And I also have a dictionary of the standard values. I need to remove any value in the list that is not found in the dictionary.

I wrote this code just to test how it works:

```
alist = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
adict = {'A':47, 'B':69, 'C':76, 'D':97}

list2 = list(adict.values())

for i in alist:
    if i not in list2:
        alist.remove(i)

print(list2,alist)
```

The output is:

```
[47, 69, 76, 97] [47, 69, 76, 95, 97]
```

What I don't understand here is **why the value 95 stayed in the new alist generated**?

When I check presence of 95 in the list2, it shows correct results as under:

INPUT:

```
print(95 in list2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
```

If I manually remove 95 from the list using `alist.remove(95)`, it does get removed.

So, can anyone please help me understand where I have gone wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't remove from a list you're iterating over, as removing from the list will move all elements in the list, making the loop skip over the next element.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Thanks. That explains my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below how to filter the list.
The general problem with the approach in your code is that you manipulate the list while you iterate over it.
Dont do that - the results are unexpected.

```
alist = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
adict = {'A': 47, 'B': 69, 'C': 76, 'D': 97}
filtered = [x for x in alist if x in set(adict.values())]
print(filtered)
```

output (Note that 95 is not in the new list)

```
[47, 69, 76, 97]
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Just a side question about the syntax here. The filtered line if re-written as a if statement nested in a for loop, I couldn't get similar result. Is that the only way to write it?

alist[:] = [i for i in alist if i in list(adict.values())] -- worked

for i in alist:
    if i in list(adict.values()):
        alist[:] = [i] -- didn't work.

Comment: @Meet the technique (`[x for x in alist if x in set(adict.values())]`) is called List Comprehension .See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 2):

You are removing items of the container on which you are iterating so it is escaping the items. That's why 95 is never got visited and remains in the list.

Try to run below version of your own code... You will get to know how actually the value of 'i' is changing.

```
alist = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
adict = {'A':47, 'B':69, 'C':76, 'D':97}

list2 = list(adict.values())
print("list2: ", list2)
print("alist: ", alist)

print("\n\n for loop")
for i in alist:
    print("in loop: ")
    print("alist: ", alist)
    print("i: ", i)
    print("list2: ", list2)
    if i not in list2:
        print("removing ", i)
        alist.remove(i)
    print("\n")

print(list2,alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the iterating object. When you iterate over any iterable object, never ever change the *iterating object* during the iteration.

For your case, you may simply use `&` in `set`

```
alist = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95]
adict = {'A':47, 'B':69, 'C':76, 'D':97}

set1 = set(alist)
set2 = set(adict.values())

alist = list(set1 & set2)
print(alist)
```

output: `[47, 69, 76]`, I removed the case `97` intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct logically.  Because `if` only executes when  the given condition is **True** .

Now, your condition is: `if i not in list2:`
So the program will accept any value other than the items of **list2** .

```
print(95 not in list2)
```

will give you True output and that's why **if** statement is executing it.